# Implement unity banner ads in swift

Tags: swift, banner, unityads

I have a game that I want to implement Unity banner ads to. I have implemented Unity rewarded and interstitial ads but there is no documentation or videos about banner ads. I had Admob Ads but Google blocked my account for 30 days so I need to transfer to Unity in this month.

Answer (score 1):

there is my implementation:

Create method like this:

```
func prepareUnityBannerAdd() {
        if UnityAds.isReady() {
            UnityAdsBanner.initialize()
            UnityAdsBanner.setDelegate(self)
            UnityAdsBanner.setBannerPosition(UnityAdsBannerPosition.topCenter)
            UnityAdsBanner.load(UNITY.banner) // This is my placment id string 
        }
}
```

in `UnityAdsDelegate` method `AdsReady` call like this:

```
func unityAdsReady(_ placementId: String) {
    prepareUnityBannerAdd()
}
```

and finally in `UnityAdsBannerDelegate` method `BannerDidLoad` do something like this:

```
func unityAdsBannerDidLoad(_ placementId: String, view: UIView) {
    bannerView.addSubview(view) // bannerView is just UIView to hold banner...
}
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: UnityAdsBanner.load is depreciated

Comment: Probably, this was year and half ago.  That was for v3.2, latest is 3.6...I think